# How come a line segment in a triangle be larger than its sides?

Tags: geometry, triangles

I have tried to find maximum value of x, and I found it 21 cm. However, the book says it is 23 cm, which is even larger than all sides of the triangle. How come?
[image: question 9]
The question is above and the answer provided by book is below.
[image: answer 9]
What I don’t understand is how come a line segment in a triangle is so large that it equals to the maximum possible length of the largest side of the triangle. Here, I can add another question with its answer where book claims the similar argument - larger line segment.
[image: question 8]
Here, I found answer 14, which is correct. However, the idea that “inner line segment > other sides” bothers me.
[image: answer 8]
I want to express my gratitude for those who spend their time to help me undertand this topic. Thank you so much!

Source: Metropol pub, YOS geometry book, 3rd edition, 2019, Ankara, pages 202-204

Comment: [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33346/scaling-down-large-images-in-posts) meta post should be helpful.

Comment: The solution looks like utter garbage to me. The statement $\max x = \max a$ is clearly wrong, as is the statement that the largest integer $a$ can be must be strictly less than $11$.

Comment: I suggest you find another book to practice. None of the choices is the correct answer, and their "solution" doesn't make any sense. From the [median length formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_(geometry)#Formulas_involving_the_medians'_lengths) $x \le \sqrt{(10^2+13^2)/2} \approx 11.6$.

Comment: An independent solution will show that the largest possible integer value of $x$ is, in fact, $11$.

Comment: Problem 8 is less of an issue: you have $|AC| \le x+8 \le  10+12$ so  if $B$ is close to the line $AC$ then $x$ will be close to $14$

Comment: @Henry The *answer* to #8 may be correct (though it could be argued that it's 13 for a proper, non-degenerate triangle). But the "proof" is wholly unintelligible to me.

Comment: For 9. The 4th line of solution is ok. C rotates about A. When points are in alignment BADC, BD is max = 11.5. When CDBA, AD is max =11.5. Where the soln goes wrong (unless there is some info missing) is 6th line, where, after establishing the limits of max(a) it seems to treat triangle ADC as being independent of the rest of the structure. Hence 23